# Colorpicker in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml, color-picker

Im currently making a simple color picker for school. Well it should be simple, however my programming in Javascript is really bad. It contains an array with the names, and a array with the codes. The codes will only contain 00, 33, 66, 99, ff, cc and the code is only 6 chars long as some of you know. With a loop i manage to print everything on screen, but now i want to make the background color the same color as the one im clicking. And i want the code of the one that im clicking in a textbox.

So heres my code:
    
     
     
        
        DHTML with jQuery: Opdracht 4

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function showPicker(source) {
            var hex = new Array('00', '33', '66','99','CC','FF');
            var colorNames = new Array(
                   "black",         // #000000
                   "weak blue",         // #000033
                   "obsure dull blue",      // #000066
                   "dark faded blue",       // #000099

              );

             var count = 0;
             document.writeln('<table width="1200" height="600">');
             for(var x in hex) {
                 document.writeln('<tr>');
                 for(var y in hex) {
                     for(var z in hex) {
                         var color = hex[x] + "" + hex[y] + "" + hex[z];
                         document.writeln('<td bgcolor="#'+color+'" title="#'+color + ' ' + colorNames[count] + '" onclick="'+source+' (\''+color+'\',\''+colorNames[count]+'\')"></td>');
                         count++;

                    }
                 }
                 document.writeln('</tr>');
             }
             document.writeln('</table>');               
        }

        showPicker('showFontColor');
    </script>



</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="color"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried a line in the onclick button, but i realised that wont work. Do you guys have any suggestions? And sorry if it looks a little messy, as I said I am a real nub in javascript.

## EDIT:

Working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>DHTML with jQuery: Opdracht 4</title>
     <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function changeBg(color){

            var currentColor = $('#printColor').val();
                $('#input').css('background', currentColor);
        }
        function printColor(color) {
                $('#printColor').val(color);

                $("#input").on("click", function() {
                    $(this).css("background", "printColor");
                });
            }           

        function changeFG() {
            var currentColor = $('#printColor').val();
                $('#input').css('color', currentColor);
        }   


            function showPicker(source) {
                var hex = new Array('00', '33',     '66','99','CC','FF');
                var colorNames = new Array(
                       "black",         // #000000
                       "weak blue",         // #000033
                       "obsure dull blue",      // #000066
  );

                 var count = 0;
                 document.writeln('<table width="800"      height="300">');
                 for(var x in hex) {
                     document.writeln('<tr>');
                     for(var y in hex) {
                         for(var z in hex) {
                             var color = hex[x] + "" +  hex[y] + "" + hex[z];
                             document.writeln('<td  bgcolor="#' + color + '" title="#' + color + ' ' + colorNames[count] + '"  onclick="javascript:printColor(\'#'+color+'\')" ' + source + '(\'' + color + '\',\'' +    colorNames[count] + '\')"></td>');

                             count++;
                             var source =     function(color){
                                 document.body.style.background = "#" + color;
                             }
                        }
                     }
                     document.writeln('</tr>');
                 }
                 document.writeln('</table>');
            }

        showPicker('showFontColor');

    </script>



    </head>

    <body> 
    <div id="input">    
        <input type="text" id="printColor" name="printColor" />
        Change <a href="#" onClick="javascript:changeBg()">Background</a> /         <a href="#" onClick="javascript:changeFG()">Foreground</a> color!
        <p> Lorem ipsum blablabla</p>
    </div>
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: For brevity's sake I think you could edit out the colors listed here past maybe 4 or 5.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `bgcolor=xxxxxx` rather than `style=background-color: xxxxxx;`?

Comment: And no Yuck, there is no specifick reason for using bgcolor. Just made the code with help of a classmate.

Answer (score 0):

Without making too much changes to your code I think this is what you want.
I just changed your array into an object so that you can map the hex code of the color to the name and declared the `changeBg` function. Just fill in the rest of the colors.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function(){
    var colorNames = {
               "000000": "black",         
               "000033": "weak blue",         
               "000066": "obsure dull blue",      
               "000099": "dark faded blue"     
               //...rest of colors

    };

    window.changeBg = function(color){

        document.body.style.background = "#" + color;
        document.getElementById("color").value = colorNames[color];
    } 

     var showPicker = function(source) {
        var hex = new Array('00', '33', '66','99','CC','FF');


         var count = 0;
         document.writeln('<table width="1200" height="600">');
         for(var x in hex) {
             document.writeln('<tr>');
             for(var y in hex) {
                 for(var z in hex) {
                     var color = hex[x] + "" + hex[y] + "" + hex[z];
                     document.writeln('<td bgcolor="#'+color+'" title="#'+color +'" onclick=changeBg(\''+color+'\')></td>');
                     count++;

                }
             }
             document.writeln('</tr>');
         }
         document.writeln('</table>');               
    }



    showPicker();

    })();

</script>




<input type="text" id="color" readonly = true/>
</body>
```

Comment: As i said, i'm really nub at this. I just dont see the structure yet. However what do you mean with defining source? I know i use a sort of parameter while using the function, but not sure where to define it.

Comment: Just put that code at the end of your script tag. When you click on the `<td>`s you call the `source` function as in your code. You pass in the color of the `<td>`s  to that function, so just use that argument to set the bgcolor of `document.body` or whatever.

Comment: Can't see to get it working.... :( you have got any other suggestions? Else i'll move on to my next assigment and ask my teacher this one.